# Sort deleted (but still open) files by size

Tags: linux, filesystems, process

This gives you list of deleted files in your filesystem occupying space (as still open):

```
find /proc/*/fd -ls 2>/dev/null | grep '(deleted)'
```

However piping filenames of file descriptors return size 0 :

```
find /proc/*/fd -ls 2>/dev/null | grep '(deleted)' \
    | sed 's!.*\(/proc[^ ]*\).*!\1!' | xargs ls -lhas
```

As they have still content , using `wc -c` provides the size :

```
find /proc/*/fd -ls 2>/dev/null | grep '(deleted)' \ 
     | sed 's!.*\(/proc[^ ]*\).*!\1!' | xargs wc -c | sort -nr |head -n 20
```

Example:

```
2809946696 total
2387677184 /proc/15050/fd/26
  67108864 /proc/1626/fd/23
  67108864 /proc/1059/fd/6
  10485760 /proc/11417/fd/298
  10485760 /proc/11417/fd/239
  10485760 /proc/11417/fd/155
  10485760 /proc/11366/fd/499
```

However, is there a better way (than `wc -c` of file descriptors marked as `(deleted)`) to find out which files occupy most space?
(or even better, which process occupy most space as keeping open handles to deleted files?)

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`,

```
ls -lLrS /proc/*/fd/*(-l0)
```

would list them ordered by file size (like `wc -c`, so not disk usage).

For disk usage, you can do:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
bydu() zstat -A REPLY +block -- $REPLY
ls -lLsU /proc/*/fd/*(-l0no+bydu)
```

(assuming GNU `ls` for it's `-U` for not sorting)

For a disk usage per process, you could do:

```
typeset -aU proc=(/proc/*/fd/*(-l0.:h:h:t))
for p ($proc) {du -Hksc /proc/$p/fd/*(-.l0) | sed -n "\$s/total\$/$p/p"} | sort -n
```

(here in kibibytes)